how to run C++ code in Visual Studio Code
I run my C++ code on Visual Studio Code with the file extension .cpp but it's not working. How can I run this on Visual Studio Code without using mingw? Is there any extension which can help me to run this code on Visual Studio Code?

Tell us what exactly you do, what errors you get, what .json files have you created if any, what extensions you're using, etc. There's nothing wrong with mingw, don't need to drop it.

Running a C++ program, anywhere and not only in VSCode, requires you to build the source code into an executable program file (with the .exe suffix), and then run the generated executable program file. You can't really build without a compiler, like the one provided by MinGW.

Read and follow the instructions. There is no other way to do this, VSCode is hard, and you must follow the instructions very carefully.

And I recommend you spend some time reading the Visual Studio Code documentation first. It will help you to set up an environment where you can build and run C++ programs.

Visual studio code is just an IDE. With the Microsoft C/C++ Extension (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) it can do all the syntax checking / highlighting / IntelliSense / etc. But it does not have an in-built compiler. It relies on having suitable compiler / linker installed already.

C++ is a compiled language meaning your program's source code must be
translated (compiled) before it can be run on your computer. The C/C++
extension doesn't include a C++ compiler or debugger, since VS Code as
an editor relies on command-line tools for the development workflow.
You need to install these tools or use the tools already installed on
your computer.

So, you need to install something like mingw, etc. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_install-a-compiler.

Without a compiler like mingw (or another gcc variant), you can’t really compile or run c++ code. You probably need to check the setup about installing gcc or clang in your environment.
What You Can Do:

Install gcc: sudo apt-get install g++ while using the remote WSL extension in Visual Studio Code.
Download clang from LLVM’s official site and configure Visual Studio Code to use it.

